# Do the levels at which Battle Master fighters gain more maneuvers refer to class level, or character level?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, character-levels, combat-maneuver, battle-master

The Battle Master subclass for fighters says that you can get more maneuvers at different levels:

> You learn two additional maneuvers of your choice at 7th, 10th, and 15th level. Each time you learn new maneuvers, you can also replace one maneuver you know with a different one.

If I have multiclassed, do I gain the maneuvers when I reach the listed character level? Or when I reach that level in Fighter?

Comment: Related: "[Is Extra Attack based on class level or character level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132032)" and "[MultiClassing and Gaining Abilities on Level up](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124684)" and "[Multiclassing: How do Ability Score Improvements work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46029)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### When you gain the specified class level

The [rules for multiclassing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#ClassFeatures) state:

> When you gain a *new level in a class*, you get its features for *that level*.

(In the quote above, "new level in a class" and "that level" refer to the same level.)

Learning additional maneuvers is a feature of the class, so it depends on your class level.

Comment: I do not disagree with this ruling, but it should be noted, there are features that scale by level that specifically call out *levels in this class* vs some that just say *level*. If that distinction was not intended to matter, why does it exist? I get it, multiclassing into battlemaster for 3 levels and gaining all the scaling options of the first level feature of the class would seem unbalanced (and probably be on every build), but I don't think it's clear cut RAW, rather a ruling on poorly written features.